# Как приводить числа, типа 123 456.50 к нормальному виду (убирать пробел)?

Tags: php, числа

Есть число вида `ABC DEF.GH`, то есть что-то вроде `123 456.50` или `5 343.20` - то есть перед тысячами пробел.

Вопрос, как приводить такие числа к нормальному виду (убирать пробел), чтобы их можно было складывать и умножать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$someLOLnumber = '1231    2              3  342423423';
$noramlNumber = str_replace(' ', '', $someLOLnumber);
//Терь normalNumber - нормальное число
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: незачто, Приходьте ще :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$var1 = (float)str_replace(' ', '', '123 456.50');
$var2 = (float)str_replace(' ', '', '5 343.20');
Теперь можно делать что хочется.
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать функции для вырезания пробелов, или заменить пробелы на пустое место. При необходимости число перевести перед этим в строку, а после - обратно. Если я правильно понял вопрос. )

Comment: Эм.. "При необходимости число перевести перед этим в строку" - с каких пор есть числовые типы с пробелами внутри?